# ni measurement studio 2012 for VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, labview, measurement-studio

Just want to be sure that measurement studio 2012 doesn't work for VS 2012 and don't waste my time to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with 2010, 2008, and 2005 thus far NOT 2012.

It will take a while until Measurement Studio support is in place for Visual Studio 2012.

[Measurement Studio 2012 Feature List](http://www.ni.com/mstudio/buy/)